# Broadcast delay of Presidential informal press encounters

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, media

President Trump seems to have largely replaced the formal press Q&A by the press secretary with informal Q&A sessions as he is leaving the White House.

Although, the press has the ability to broadcast these informal meetings live, as they had done with previous, for some reason the media cannot broadcast these sessions live.

Is there a reason for this, that some meetings with the press are live but the "leaving the White House" sessions are not?

Asking this on Politics because the reason maybe a policy matter of the government.

Answer (score 2):

The Formal press briefings had a measure of predictable regularity. Stories and the news hour could be scheduled around the event, to allow for live airing with minimal interruption of other programming.

In the informal ambush of the President as he moves towards he helicopter, while there may be a schedule of his activities it isn't the most robust. This challenges the media with planning for airings and surrounding content.

Comment: A challenge for the media "for airing" might be reasonable for networks that have schedules to maintain, but doesn't seem logical for cable news, that have live reports all the time. So, is this answer something you've seen reported/published  factually or is this your speculation?

Comment: Probably worth adding to this that if he doesn't answer questions or doesn't give controversial and/or important answers, then there's not much point in interrupting things to broadcast it in real time - it's not news.